# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null - Select2.js on selection any option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Select2 on dropdown always gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null`, when i select any data in select box it gives me error and it not call change event function

> html codes

```
 <select name="sono[]" id="sonoDetails" class="select2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="">Select SO No</option>
    <option value="5" data-bookingtime="2015-10-16 21:00:00">5</option>
    <option value="4" data-bookingtime="2015-10-17 20:15:00">4</option>                         
</select>
```

Js codes to get data on `initialize select2` and `on change` event handler

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select2").select2();
    $(document).on("change","select[name='sono[]']",function(){//
        var me = $(this);
        var sono = me.select2("val");
          console.log(sono);
    }); 
 });
```

It run fine only first time after that its always return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null` in js...

I want change event work for every selection but now it runs only once

help to solve this problem

Comment: which version of Select2.js is it?

Comment: @LinYuan  Select2 version 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should chain the select2() and val() functions in jquery instead of trying to use the select2() function with val as its parameter.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', "select[name='sono[]']", function() {
    var sono = $('.select2').select2().val()
    console.log(sono)
  })
})
```

`

Comment: still not working,..... its work only once, second and other time its not on event

Comment: Thanks for help. Its binding issue on js. Solve by binding

Answer (score 2):

You can Try This...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select2").select2().on("change", function (e) {
        console.log("change",$(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ve3ntc6q/

Comment: Thanks for help. Its binding issue on js. Solve by binding

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

I fixed it by making sure all JSON objects that I pass into my select2 is not null or empty. Then everything works fine. ***This occurs on my Select 4.0.5 version.***

Comment: Yes in this version its working file as normal jQeury

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. This solved my problem

```js
$("select").change(function () {
...
});
with:
$("select").on("select2:select select2:unselecting", function () {
...
});
```

Comment: Does not work another function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the data attribute values using the following code.

```
$("#sonoDetails").on("change", function(e) {
       var bookingtime = $(this).find(":selected").data("bookingtime");
});
```